# Getting 'DatabaseError' object has no attribute 'message' in DJango

Tags: django, database

I am trying to run the following code here to save information to the database. I have seen other messages - but - it appears that the solutions are for older versions of `Python/DJango` (as they do not seem to be working on the versions I am using now: `Python 3.6.3` and `DJango 1.11.7`

```
if form.is_valid():
    try:
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        item.tenantid = tenantid
        item.save()
        message = 'saving data was successful'
    except DatabaseError as e:
        message = 'Database Error: ' + str(e.message)
```

When doing so, I get an error message the error message listed below. How can I fix this so I can get the message found at the DB level printed out?

```
'DatabaseError' object has no attribute 'message'
Request Method:
POST
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storeowner/edit/
Django Version:
1.11.7
Exception Type:
AttributeError
Exception Value:
'DatabaseError' object has no attribute 'message'
Exception Location:
C:\WORK\AppPython\ContractorsClubSubModuleDEVELOP\libmstr\storeowner\views.py in edit_basic_info, line 40
Python Executable:
C:\WORK\Software\Python64bitv3.6\python.exe
Python Version:
3.6.3
Python Path:
['C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubSubModuleDEVELOP',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\OracleInstantClient64Bit\\instantclient_12_2',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\DLLs',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\lib',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6',
 'C:\\Users\\dgmufasa\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubSubModuleDEVELOP\\libintgr',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubSubModuleDEVELOP\\libmstr',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubSubModuleDEVELOP\\libtrans',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubBackofficeCode\\libintgr',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubBackofficeCode\\libmstr',
 'C:\\WORK\\TRASH\\tempforcustomer\\tempforcustomer\\libtempmstr',
 'C:\\WORK\\AppPython\\ContractorsClubBackofficeCode\\libtrans',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\WORK\\Software\\Python64bitv3.6\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2017.3-py3.6.egg']
Server time:
Sat, 9 Dec 2017 08:42:49 +0000
```

Comment: Exceptions don't have the `message` attribute any more in Python 3. They have args. See python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change

```
str(e.message)
```

to

```
str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

**some  change**

> str(e.message)

**to**

> HttpResponse(e.message)